# Relative Layout Does Not Align 3 Images Correctly

Tags: uiimageview, imageview, android-relativelayout, android

I have a RelativeLayout which i'd like to use to create two side by side ImageViews (h1 and h2) with another image centered on top (ui3)

For some reason the images do not seem to align correctly when using the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    tools:context=".Home" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_pw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ui3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ui2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/header1"
        android:src="@drawable/h2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/h2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/h1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### Expected Result:

[image]

### Result:

[image]

To be perfectly clear: I simply need to create what appears to be one solid image out of the 3 individual images:

### RESOURCES:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYZIt.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzaYd.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB9KS.png
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is this not a legitimate question?

Comment: Upload an image showing what is the UI you are expecting. we can try to modify the code and post it for you. Also, please mention the size of your drawable resources so that we can create dummy images at our end for debugging.

Comment: I added the expected resulting image (h1 is 539 x 207 h2 is 180 x 207 and ui3 is 720 x 945)

Comment: You have 2 buttons with content as "text". Where is that in screenshot ?

Comment: They are set to hidden (as desired)

Comment: In your screenshot, update the name of view IDs so i can design it in xml. Your question is not clear at all. Kindly Give all details clearly.

Comment: I'm trying to align  in a relative layout - I posted an updated screenshot (I think that will clarify more than renaming the viewIDS - but I can if you still dont understand what I'm trying to do)

Comment: Understand what I'm trying to accomplish now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43855/discussion-between-prem-and-user3113035)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem in your code** - Circular reference between the views in layout.

**Problem 1**

This imageview is taking the complete screen size.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ui3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         />
```

**Problem 2**

This image view is creating circular reference.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/h1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/h2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />
```